# Google Line Chart Customization

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have these line charts here with real time data from an arduino.

[image]

What i want to do is to make the first graph (Temperature) better looking. I want to have always some gaps from the top and bottom (Like humidity) and i want to increase the width of the Y Axis of temperature. Is this possible ?

Both charts has run with exactly the same settings:

```
 function drawTemperature() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.3/Charts/chart_temperature.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (jsonData) {
            // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

            var options =  {
                'title': 'Temperature',
                'width': 1200,
                'height': 600
                //'legend.alignment' : 'start',
                //'hAxis.baseline' : 5,
                //'chartArea.top' : 20,
                //'chartArea.left' : 500
                //'focusTarget' : 'category'
                //'animation.easing' : 'inAndOut'
                //colors:['blue','#004411'],
                //'hAxis.maxValue' : 30,
                //'hAxis.showTextEvery' : 0.1,
                //'hAxis.logScale' : 'true',
                //'hAxis.gridlines.color' : '#00CC00',
                //'hAxis.maxAlternation' : 10,
                //'hAxis.viewWindow.max' : 10

                //'curveType': 'function'
            };

            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_temperature'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    });
}

 function drawHumidity() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.3/Charts/chart_humidity.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (jsonData) {
            // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_humidity'));
            chart.draw(data, {width: 1200, height: 600});
        }
    });
}

 function drawVisualization() {
               drawTemperature();
               drawHumidity();

            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "increase the width of the Y axis"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create "gaps" at the top and bottom of you chart by setting the vAxis.minValue and vAxis.maxValue options to values less than the minimum and maximum (respectively) of your chart's data.  Here's one way you might do this:

```
var range = data.getColumnRange(1);
var options = {
    title: 'Temperature',
    width: 1200,
    height: 600,
    vAxis: {
        minValue: range.min - 1,
        maxValue: range.max + 1
    }
};
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i wanted to do. THanks a lot :)